# Closeable objects associated with HttpSession

Tags: java, http, servlets, struts, httpsession

I can't find any way to destroy Closeable objects associated with HttpSession properly. It would be nice to have some event or callback invoked while session is invalidating. Wonder why I need it? I have connection associated with session, and it is not connection to DB, so I can't use pool.

It seems that my case is uncomon as I didn't found any relative questions. Is it impossible to detect session close event? If so, why it is made impossible? Maybe my case is just a result of stupid approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The servlet API provides [javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html/http/HttpSessionListener.html) in order that you can get notified when a session is created or destroyed.

Another option would be that your objects in the session implement `HttpSessionBindingListener`. When they are unbound from the session or when the session is destroyed they will get notified and can then close themselves.

Comment: Hm... nice. It's strange i couldn't find it. Anyway, thank you. P.S. Your url is path to local file ;)